# Using Rake To Scrape ASP.NET Page

Tags: asp.net, screen-scraping, rake

Is it possible, and if so how, do I use RAKE to scrape an ASP.Net Application (very simple, just 2 login forms) - Basically a spider bot/web crawler.

I only ask since I've heard this mentioned before and wonder what method I would use to go about doing it?

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you intending to actually use the login forms after converting them?

Comment: Sorry, have rephrased question.....I need to basically make a web crawler..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what RAKE is, and Googling isn't helping much, but you could try **WebPoacher**:

http://josh1.com/Projects/WebPoacher/

Web poacher is a bit of Windows software I wrote after asking a similar question on here.

It will crawl websites and get static HTML for you.

Comment: @Goober - which version? I am running Chrome 3.0.195.27 with no problems on several PCs...

Comment: @Goober - Also, any indication on what actually happens? Does it load? Could you download it? Does it crash Chrome? Does it jump up and down?